# prove that f is constant if $f(2^x)=f(3^x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

I am trying to prove that when $f$ is continuous for all non-negative real number and
$$f(2^x)=f(3^x),$$ then $f$ is constant.

If $f(2^x)=f(3^x)$ then from here I can say that $f(2^x/2^n)=f(3^x/3^n)$ and then I can use limit when $n\to\infty$, but I am not sure how to make connection with $f(x)$ function itself to prove.

Could you give me any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question only makes sense if $f$ is a function that is *only* defined for non-negative real numbers

Answer (score 0):

Your question is problematic as stated. I suspect that you mean to ask the following:

> Suppose that $f:[0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$ is continuous and that for all $x \in \Bbb R$, we have
> $$
> f(2^x) = f(3^x).
> $$
> Prove that $f$ is constant.

Here is a hint:

- With the substitution $y = 3^x$, rewrite this condition as $f(y) = f(g(y))$ for all $y > 0$, where $g(y) = y^{\alpha}$, and $\alpha = \log(2)/\log(3)$.
- Note that for all $0<y<1$, we have $y < g(y) < 1$. Similarly, for all $y > 1$, we have $1 < g(y) < y$.